# Ethereum transaction stuck, out of gas

Tags: transactions, out-of-gas, gas-limit, confirmations, poloniex

I sent some ethereum from my Coinomi wallet to a Poloniex trading account and it has been over 8 days and it has still not been received. over 30k confirmations and steadily rising and it appears all of the gas has been used and that the transaction is stuck. At this point is there anyway of pushing the transaction through or getting my Ethereum back? Yes I sent more than the minimum required deposit (0.5 ETH).

TxHash: 0x91f238cbe405c70ac04e6328c590bf1995e741f2890afb810688fed3e91feed7

Etherscan: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x91f238cbe405c70ac04e6328c590bf1995e741f2890afb810688fed3e91feed7

Thanks :)

Comment: The transaction has succeeded, and it cannot be reversed. You have to ask Poloniex support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires 3rd-party support